# Excel-Add-in-ASPNET-QuickBooks sample from github not loading in Excel

Tags: excel, add-in, quickbooks, excel-addins

I have just downloaded and unzipped and followed the "change your IDs" part of the add-in steps here https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Add-in-ASPNET-QuickBooks

When I try to load it by pressing F5 (Start Debug), Excel does start, and it looks like it's trying to load in a pane on the right (not a button on the ribbon like I'm expecting?), but it says Loading... for a while and then a red-X pops for a second too fast that I can see/click, but then it goes back to  Loading... and my HDD is thrashing..
There are no errors that I can see, but I would like to know what that red-X is, and ultimately have the button show on the ribbon.

I don't have to do an "install" per-se, do I? I think that side pane is doing the install, but failing, and I can't find a log anywhere..

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed an Excel update..
I had ProcMon running and tried to analyze minidumps and tried everything else that I could think of..

Still a touch of wonkiness (like having to copy my 32-bit .exe as the 64) but it at least loads in Excel now.